# How to prevent the components of a inherited control of appearing for editing in Visual Studio Properties Pane?

Tags: c#, winforms, inheritance

I created a base `Form` that has two buttons. I added two properties which these buttons were assigned to:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace PresentationLayer.Views
{
    public partial class BaseDialogView : Form
    {
        [Browsable(false)]
        protected Button _okBtn;

        [Browsable(false)]
        protected Button _cancelBtn;

        public BaseDialogView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            _okBtn = this.okBtn;
            _cancelBtn = this.cancelBtn;
        }
    }
}
```

When this base `Form` is inherited, the properties `_okBtn` and `_cancelBtn` appear for editing in Properties Pane of the derived `Form`:

How to prevent these properties of appearing in Properties Pane?

Comment: Try `[EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]`

Comment: Hi, Lars! I Tried, but it doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: Inheriting Forms in WinForms has always been a painful experience.  Try putting the buttons inside a panel.  It won't prevent the selection, but it should lock them down a bit in the new form.

Comment: Those are not properties but Fields. Add `{ get; }` or `{ get; set;}` and decorate with `[Browsable(false), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]`. Note that by doing this, those two Buttons cannot be accessed or modified in the Designer of the derived classes.

Comment: @Jimi Good catch.  I missed the missing property setters.